# How to detect if finger is pressed at app startup?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I would like to detect if the user has their finger held on the screen when my app starts so that I can perform some different functionality.

Most of what I've seen is in regards to gestures but I don't think that would work since the user will already have their finger held down when the app starts. It would be extra cool if I could detect how many fingers so that I could go directly to a different page for two fingers.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/high-performance-touch-interface-wpdev-wp7dev/

The TouchFrameEventArgs that occurs provides a mechanism to query multiple touch points

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touchframeeventargs.gettouchpoints(v=vs.95).aspx

In my post i only deal with primary touch ponit but the GetTouchPoints method will give you all touch points as a collection

Comment: Thanks Dave, it's funny I read your blog post before but I assumed you had to hook up to the event before the user pressed their finger down. I will try it out tonight!

Comment: the event is trigged based on "up", "down" or "move" by user. if your users are absolutely still and are not generating any touch events, you are in a difficult place :)

Comment: I tested this and unfortunately if the finger was already pressed as the app is starting then no touch events are fired until a finger down event is detected.

Comment: I think that it's just not possible currently, so I'm accepting your answer as it's the closest solution possible.